# Java:92: error: unexpected type

Tags: java

I am creating the card game blackjack and am trying to have the user pick the amount of computer players that they will play against.  I tried using a for loop to cycle through every unspecified computer player's hand and modify it with computerChoice functions which tells the computer to add cards to hand or stay.  I am running into an error at "hands.get(counter) because that is not a variable (hands is an array list that holds array lists for each computers hands.)  I could not figure out a way around this issue and was curious if this can even work if modified.

```
for(int counter = 0; comNum>counter; counter++){
      hands.get(counter) = coms.get(counter).computerChoice(hands.get(counter), coms.get(counter), myList, myMap, values.get(counter), busts.get(counter), define);
    }
```

Comment: You can't assign something to the result of a method call. So `hands.get(counter) = xxx` is not a valid statement.

Comment: You cannot assign something *to* `hands.get(counter)`.

Comment: I know that I cannot do that and I am asking if there is a way to modify an array list of array lists

Comment: what do u want to modify here?

Comment: There are programming languages where a method may return something that you can meaningfully assign to. Not Java: here a method returns a *value*, while for assignment you need a *variable* on the left side of `=`.

Comment: Without a bit more of code, such as the declaration of `hands`, I cannot tell what the solution to your problem may be. Surely there is one.

Comment: If `hands` is an `ArrayList` or any other kind of `List`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would want to use the `set()`-method of the presumed collection you are using. Something like

```
hands.set(counter, 
    coms.get(counter).computerChoice(hands.get(counter), coms.get(counter),
    myList, myMap, values.get(counter), busts.get(counter), define)
);
```

should do what you want it to. The `set()`-method changes the stored reference at the selected index, so that the modified entry points towards the specified object. The `=` assignment operator is another way to change what object a *variable* points towards.

However, since methods only return *values* (and not a variable), there is no way for you to assign it any sort of "pointer".

Hope this helped!